# Any alternatives to the componentResized method in ComponentAdapter

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe, componentlistener

When I implement the code below, the method is only called when the user releases the mouse after resizing a frame. I want a method that is called continuously as the user is resizing the frame. What can I do instead?

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent comp) {
        System.out.println("Resized");
        }
      });
```

Comment: 1) Why?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why? Because my frame contains a JScrollPane. I have the size of the JScrollPane staying proportional to the size of the frame, and it's to choppy-looking using the above code.

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel That's the responsibility of the layout manager...

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. But I don't really know I would go about doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//frame.addComponentListener(...
frame.getContentPane().addComponentListener(...
```

Comment: Happy 100. To format code, select the sample and click the `{}` button on the message posting/editing form.